# java finding primes that have digits that add to a multiple of 10 in a range

Tags: java, primes

I'm writing a piece of code that finds primes that have digits that sum up to a multiple of ten, from `start` to `end`, but I'm having a hard time finding the mistake in my code that is finding them and other unessescary primes that don't sum to a multiple of ten.

```
    void funPrimes(int start, int end) {
    int ten = 0;
    for (int n = start; n < end; n++){
        int current = n;
        while (current > 0){
            ten += current%10;
            current=current/10;
        }
        if(isPrime(n)&&ten%10==0) println(n);
    }
}
boolean isPrime(int num){
    boolean p = true;
    for(int i = 2; i < num; i++){
        if(num%i ==0) return false;
    }
    return p;
}
```

For example, if `start = 1` and `end = 2048`, then the only numbers that should be printed out are 19, 37, 73, 127, 163, 181, 271...

But when I run my code, the numbers that come up are 19, 47, 59, 71, 79, 103, 139, 179, 199...

Comment: you should add some sample output to show how your code is going wrong

Comment: I downloaded and ran the code. I gave it start = 1 and end = 20. The only number that was printed out was 19. It's so annoying when you go out of your way to help with someone's question and it turns out the author didn't even run their own code with their own example...

Comment: Sorry, I just took two easy numbers that came off the top of my head. If I used bigger numbers, such as 1 to 2048, then the only numbers should be 19, 37, 73, 109, 127, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you do not reset the variable `ten` every time you loop. This works:

```
void funPrimes(int start, int end) {
    int ten = 0;
    for (int n = start; n < end; n++) {
        ten = 0;
        int current = n;
        while (current > 0) {
            ten += current % 10;
            current = current / 10;
        }
        if (isPrime(n) && ten % 10 == 0) {
            System.out.println(n);
        }
    }
}
```

In my opinion it makes the code much cleaner if you also break the function to determine if a number is divisible by 10 into its own method:

```
void funPrimes(int start, int end) {
    for (int n = start; n < end; n++) {
        if (isPrime(n) && digitsAddToTen(n)) {
            System.out.println(n);
        }
    }
}

boolean isPrime(int num) {
    boolean p = true;
    for (int i = 2; i < num; i++) {
        if (num % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return p;
}

boolean digitsAddToTen(int num) {
    int digitTotal = 0;
    while (num > 0) {
        digitTotal += num % 10;
        num = num / 10;
    }
    return (digitTotal % 10 == 0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I works, but I guess the extra function was helpful, and less complicated, but not really necessary

Comment: This smacks of something that should have been closed as a typo... but then again I'm not sure.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes Feel free to vote as such. I'm not sure if I agree or disagree, but in general I have no problem helping someone figure out their issue and then closing the question because it is unlikely to help others.

Comment: @RandyHuang No problem, happy to help. The extra function is not necessary but clean and well organized code is always better than the opposite. As your projects get larger, you will find that organizing your code well will lead to less bugs, more portability, and more re-usability, not to mention how much easier it is for people (like SO, who you are asking for help) to read. Please remember to upvote and accept if this helped =]